# finding integral of f(x) = x

Tags: integration

[image]

Why is it that when you use the partition 0 =x0 < x1 < … < xn = b, instead of specifying what each point of subdivision is, you get U(f,P)-L(f,P)= ∑(Mi - mi)Δxi = f(b)(b-0)= b^2?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $U(f)=\inf\{U(f,P): P~\text{is ANY partition of }[a,b]\}$, and similar to $L(f)$.

Of course, in this case, because we want $L(f)\geq\dfrac{b^{2}}{2}$, if we pick $Q_{n}=\{0,b/n,2b/n,(n-1)/b,b\}$, it is true that $L(f)\geq L(f,Q_{n})$, when we take $n\rightarrow\infty$, one has $L(f)\geq\dfrac{b^{2}}{2}$.

Comment: why don't we get (b^2)/2 when we don't specify in terms of n what the points of partition are?

Comment: Wait, by the way what do you mean by specify what the points of partition are and $p$ is arbitrary? If you specify what the points are, then the partition is just an instance, not arbitrary.

Comment: Do you see how if i use {x0,....xn}, and then compute ∑(Mi - mi)Δxi = f(b)(b-0)= b^2, but when you use {0,b/n ...(n-1)/b,b},you get (b^2)/2?

Comment: Yes, true, but the point is, if we argue with the reasoning like, since $P_{n}=\{0,b/n,...,(n-1)/b,b\}$ satisfies $U(f,P_{n})=b^{2}/2$, then $U(f)=b^{2}/2$, this is simply not valid.

Comment: never mind I misunderstood the solution

Comment: I get it now thanks